# Change the field label name in lightning-record-form component

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
<lightning-record-form
    object-api-name={objectApiName}
    fields={fields}
>
</lightning-record-form>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class RecordFormCreateExample extends LightningElement {
    // objectApiName is "Account" when this component is placed on an account record page
    @api objectApiName;

    fields = [
       { fieldApiName: 'Name' },
       { fieldApiName: 'AnnualRevenue'},
       { fieldApiName: 'Industry' }
    ];
}
```

I want to change the Annual Revenue field label to something else than Revenue. I have tried below code using `fieldLabelName` variable name but it didn't work.

```
fields = [
     { fieldApiName: 'Name' },
     { fieldApiName: 'AnnualRevenue', fieldLabelName: 'Label Changed'},
     { fieldApiName: 'Industry' }
];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lightning-record-form`, `lightning-record-edit-form`, and `lightning-record-view-form` do not support custom field labels. The labels are rendered based on [getObjectInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info) call. For components that accept a list of fields or columns, and allows a label to be set, the property will always simply be called `label`, as opposed to `fieldLabelName` or some other complicated affair. See [`lightning-datatable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) as an example. If you absolutely need custom labels, you'll need to create a custom UI.

Comment: Alternatively, change the label everywhere via override or translation. :D

Answer (score 3):

`lightning-record-form` doesn't support custom field labels, but you can achieve it with  either `lightning-record-edit-form` or `lightning-record-view-form` since both [`lightning-input-field`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/specification) and [`lightning-output-field`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-output-field/specification) support `variant="label-hidden"`.

**Edit Form**:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form
        density="comfy"
        object-api-name={objectApiName}>

        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-var-p-around_x-small">
                <lightning-input-field class="slds-form-element_stacked" field-name={nameField}></lightning-input-field>
            </div>

            <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-var-p-around_x-small">
                <div class="slds-form-element__label slds-var-m-left_xx-small" onclick={handleFocus}>{aCustomLabel}</div>
                <lightning-input-field class="slds-form-element_stacked" field-name={annualRevenueField} variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input-field>
            </div>

            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-center slds-var-m-top_x-small slds-size_full">
                <lightning-button label="Cancel" title="Cancel" onclick={handleCancel}></lightning-button>
                <lightning-button label="Submit" title="Submit" type="submit" variant="brand" class="slds-var-m-left_small" ></lightning-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>

</template>
```

**JS**

```js
handleFocus(event) {
    event.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.focus();
}
```

**Preview**:
[image: edit-form]

It works the same way with a `lightning-record-view-form`:

```html
<lightning-record-view-form
    density="comfy"
    object-api-name={objectApiName}
    record-id={recordId}>
    
    <div class="slds-form-element__label slds-var-m-left_xx-small">{aCustomlabel}</div>
    <lightning-output-field class="slds-form-element_stacked" field-name={annualRevenueField} variant="label-hidden"></lightning-output-field>
</lightning-record-view-form>
```

Comment: This kind of works, but then the labels don't behave like labels (e.g. click to focus). Last time I ran into a similar situation, I just made an entire UI component for it.

Comment: @sfdcfox Fair enough, but I thought OP want to just change the label's value, anyway `lightning-input-field` exposes `focus()` method, so the click to focus can be added. I updated the answer.